# Beamer: How do I remove the gap/margin on top of slides?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I have the following beamer slide:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pic test}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item don't show the image yet
      \item wait for it...
      \item show the image now
      \item keep showing the image
      \item keep showing the image still
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage} \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=9cm]{images/code.jpg}
        \caption{here's the image!}
      \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**How do I remove the gap at the top?**

[image]